# Find $q(e_1)$ and $q(e_2)$ from $q(x)=x.Ax$

Tags: quadratic-forms

> **Problem**: If $A = \begin{pmatrix} -6 & 3 \\ 3 & -1\end{pmatrix}$ and $q(x)=x.Ax$
> then $q(e_1)$ = ? and $q(e_2)$ = ?

> **Attempt**:
> $$
> x.Ax= \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -6 & 3 \\ 3 & -1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2\end{pmatrix}
> = -6x_1^2+6x_1x_2-1x_2^2
> $$
> x.Ax gets the same matrix as A.

I've been studying Quadratic Form and Matrix Norm. I know how to get eigenvalues and eigenvectors. But I don't understand what $q(e_1)$ and $q(e_2)$ are?

Comment: Use $e_1=(1,0)^T$ and $e_2=(0,1)^T$ and multiply $e_iAe_i$.

Comment: Now that you've mentioned it, that make sense. Thank you!